# VBA code to combine two Workbooks into one Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if it is possible to bring two workbooks (sheet1) into one worksheet (master workbook). I need to have two data together in one worksheet.

Any help is really appreciated. Below are screenshots for further details if helps.

Two files:

1. Fundraise-pages(1).csv
2. Supporters(1).csv

Please see the attached for further details if help?

[image]

---

Thank you for looking into this.

File 1 and File 2 data - both have the same email addresses.

Importantly I would like a macro to pull data to identify or even match for both email addresses. If found then add it onto a worksheet.

For example on the worksheet (master) there should be a data file 1 on the left hand side and the data file 2 on the right hand side including headings.

I hope you can see my images clearly?

Regards

V

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZSxn.gif)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px98q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overview to start with:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

[Vba Import CSV files to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784907/vba-import-csv-files-to-excel#37785386)

Proposal:
Using the connection via PowerQuery allows you to further process them as tables and also join/merge them into one while you can see and follow each step of the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  We need to do with VBA for our users.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want. Feel free to change the code to suit your needs.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Source code:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm

Also, check this out.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Comment: Hi Thank you for this. I am very new with VBA.  I have two excel files and want to copy both of them (data) onto a worksheet side by side please depending on a match function relying on email addresses if found.  Two files are located in C:\Drive.

Comment: Just made a small update to my original post. Try that AddIn. It's pretty flexible in what it can do!!

Comment: Hi I copy your codes  and paste it in the macro. I get a prompt error message: Sub or Function not defined.  'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

Comment: The functions were not highlighted with Ctrl+K. I just fixed it. Please try it again.

Comment: Thanks. When run the macro and I get nothing, just blank worksheet. It seems that I cannot see that with the codes not pull 2 files (2 workbooks) from my c\: drive to a worksheet (master).

Comment: It works fir for me. You can do @ things.
#1) Change this: Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")
To this: Set CopyRng = sh.UsedRange

#2) Hit the F8 key over and over to step through the code line by line. You will have to debug it and determine exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: I copy the codes you sent and paste it into a new workbook's macro and then save it as test.xlsm. I press F8 to see the reaction of the code.  I still cannot see this macro workbook to pull data in from each downloaded file to a workbook.

Comment: I gave you everything you need. Not sure what's going one now. I guess you need to learn VBA a little better, and then you can be more productive. Don't give up!!

Comment: Thank you for your time on this matter which is much appreciated. I agree with your points. I won’t give up. Thanks again. 